# riak content_type no method error

Tags: ruby, riak, nomethoderror

I have the 4 node riak setup running on my os x machine. I have the following program -

```
require 'riak'




class RiakClient < Riak::Client
    #attr_accessor :bucket

    def initialize(hosts="")
        return Riak::Client.new(:nodes => [{:http_port => 8091},{:http_port =>8092},{:http_port=>8093},{:http_port =>8094}])
    end

    def get_me(bucket, key)
        obj = self.bucket(bucket).get(key)
        puts obj.data
    end

    def put_me(bucket, key, data, content_type)
        obj=self.bucket(bucket).get_or_new(key)
        puts obj.class
        obj.content_type=content_type
        obj.raw_data=data
        obj.store
    end
end



if __FILE__ == $0
    my_client=RiakClient.new
    my_client.put_me("doc", "index.html", "some data goes here", "text/html")
    hash=my_client.get_me("doc", "index.html")
end
```

I am getting the following error

```
NilClass
riak_client.rb:32:in `put_me': undefined method `content_type=' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from riak_client.rb:42:in `<main>'
```

Do I have to import the RiakBucket and RiakObject classes? It seems that the RiakBucket methods cannot be accessed here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual question here is: why does `get_or_new` return nil?

It's probably because your `initialize()` method returns a new Riak::Client, but the Riak::Client that is your parent object never gets initialized. Try putting a call to super instead of the `return Riak::Client.new` in `initialize`.

Subclassing Riak::Client is a bit dubious here. I would tend to delegate to it instead.